# Change style (in ResourceDictionary) from code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="MainMenuLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

If I want change the font size or color, what can I do ? This code doesn't work .

```
 Application.Current.Resources("MainMenuLabelStyle") = 25
```

This is the xaml

```
  <TextBlock Text="Uscita" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  TextAlignment="Left"  Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource MainMenuLabelStyle}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before a style is used for the first time in a WPF application, it is sealed for performance reasons and it is not possible to modify it anymore. You can read it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.issealed(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, if you want to change your style, you have to options. The first one (the easiest one) is to declare as many styles as you need and put them in your `ResourceDictionary`.

The second solution is to consider that a `Setter` is a `DependencyObject`, so you can bind its dependency properties. In this case your style will become:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag.Foreground, TargetNullValue=Red, FallbackValue=Red}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag.FontSize, TargetNullValue=18, FallbackValue=18}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag.FontFamily, TargetNullValue=Arial, FallbackValue=Arial}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now you can change the style just by setting the `Tag` property of every `TextBlock` control:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Uscita" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource MainMenuLabelStyle}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Uscita" TextAlignment="Left"  Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource MainMenuLabelStyle}">
        <TextBlock.Tag>
            <local:StyleConfig FontSize="50" FontFamily="Tahoma" Foreground="Orange" />
        </TextBlock.Tag>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see the first `TextBlock` will use the style as it was declared. On the other side, the second `TextBlock` will use a modified version of the original style.

Of course, in order to make this option work correctly, you must create a class (`StyleConfig` in my sample), which could be something like this:

```
public class StyleConfig
{
    public string Foreground { get; set; }
    public string FontSize { get; set; }
    public string FontFamily { get; set; }
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
Application.Current.Resources("MainMenuLabelStyle") = 25
```

1) Wrong syntax. `Application.Current.Resources["MainMenuLabelStyle"]`

2) `Application.Current.Resources["MainMenuLabelStyle"]` this code will return object with type `Style`, not style property `Font Size`.

You can create new `Style` and replace it in ResourceDictionary.

Comment: How create new style ?

Comment: You can create many xaml-styles as said @Il Vic (I think it is better solution), or you can create style in C# code. _**My note:** You do not need change your style in c# because xaml-style is a constant (something like that), that means you can create many styles and switch them in c#, or create styles in c# and add\replace it in dictionary on the fly (last variant can be used in some ThemeManager app)._